# Custom intent is being confirmed over and over again, and never handled

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

I've inherited a codebase that implements a half-baked implementation of custom intents and shortcuts. One issue that I can't figure out is the one described by the title.

On paper, everything seems to work. When the confirm() method's completion handler is called, the response code passed is '.ready'; the UI extension boots up correctly, everything. In the UI extension, cancellation works great. However, when "confirm" is pressed in the UI extension, it just runs through the same confirmation flow again.

So why is the handle() method in my intent handler not being called? Is there something I'm missing? Anyone see any holes in what I'm describing? Unfortunately I can't put large swathes of code into this post, but if anyone would like to see anything specific just let me know and I'll start adding small snippets.

Comment: you need to share code.

Answer (score 0):

Ran it on a real device and it worked. Not an ideal solution (especially if you're doing watch stuff, with those ridiculous build times) but it works.

SoupChef had the same issue for me & a coworker of mine, so we went ahead and filed a bug report with Apple as well.